# Turn this list into a drop down?

Tags: categories, html.dropdownlistfor

So i've been playing around with this guys tutorials, takeing elements from each one into a single app. https://mackenziechild.me/12-in-12/

in this specific tutorial https://mackenziechild.me/12-in-12/7/ we make categories with the rails console

now cause im adding it on top of his reddit clone, with a sidebar added in from his blog, i cant just copy paste his application.html.erb (well he uses haml in this one, but his first two i copied used erb, so im sticking with it instead of rewriting everything)

My problem comes in that i tinkered with the categories in the application.html for like 2 hours couldn't get them nice, so i just threw list tags over the category line cause it was the only way i could figure it out that sorta worked

but now i want to add in a few more categories on top of my existing 4, and the list of categories are gonna take up too much room at this point, i figure a dropdown is fine, but cant figure it out

in the application.html i got

```
<div id="content" class="col-md-9 center-block">
<% Category.all.each do |category| %>
  <li><%= link_to category.name, links_path(category: category.name) %></li>
<% end %>
```

What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

`select_tag "categories", options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, "id", "name")`

You can learn more about this [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select).